# AssertionError: assertion failed: object serializer should have only one bound reference but there are 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Java POJO `RawSpan` with the following schema. My question is only around the `trace_id` but I am mentioning the entire schema for completeness sake:

```
root
 |-- customer_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- trace_id: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- entity_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- customer_id: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- entity_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- entity_type: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- entity_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attributes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- attribute_map: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- binary_value: binary (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value_map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- related_entity_ids: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ids: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |-- resource: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attributes: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- attribute_map: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- binary_value: binary (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- event: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- customer_id: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- event_id: binary (nullable = false)
 |    |-- event_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entity_id_list: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |-- resource_index: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- attributes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attribute_map: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- binary_value: binary (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |-- start_time_millis: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- end_time_millis: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- metrics: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- metric_map: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- binary_value: binary (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |-- event_ref_list: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- trace_id: binary (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- event_id: binary (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- ref_type: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- enriched_attributes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- attribute_map: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- binary_value: binary (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value_map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |-- jaegerFields: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- flags: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- logs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- warnings: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |-- http: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- request: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- scheme: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- host: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- method: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- path: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- query_string: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- session_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- cookies: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- user_agent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- size: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- headers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- host: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- authority: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- content_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- path: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- x_forwarded_for: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- user_agent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- cookie: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- other_headers: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- params: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- status_code: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- status_message: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- size: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- cookies: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- headers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- content_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- set_cookie: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- other_headers: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |-- grpc: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- request: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- method: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- host_port: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- call_options: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- size: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- metadata: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- request_metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- authority: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- content_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- path: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- x_forwarded_for: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- user_agent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- other_metadata: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- response: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- size: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- status_code: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- status_message: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- error_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- error_message: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- metadata: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- response_metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- content_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- other_metadata: map (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |-- sql: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- query: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- db_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- params: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sqlstate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- service_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rpc: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- system: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- service: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- method: string (nullable = true)
 |-- received_time_millis: long (nullable = true)
```

I am try to group these spans by `traceId` (type: `ByteBuffer`, it's a POJO) in Spark as:

```
implicit  val spanEncoder: Encoder[RawSpan] = Encoders.bean(classOf[RawSpan])
implicit val bytebufEncoder: Encoder[ByteBuffer] = Encoders.bean(classOf[ByteBuffer])

val rawSpansDataset = input1.select("value").select(from_avro(..)).select("from_avro(value).*").as[RawSpan]

val groupedSpans = rawSpansDataset.groupByKey(rawSpan => rawSpan.getTraceId())

groupedSpans.count.show
```

The above instruction throws the following exception:

```
AssertionError: assertion failed: object serializer should have only one bound reference but there are 0
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.$anonfun$tuple$2(ExpressionEncoder.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.tuple(ExpressionEncoder.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset.aggUntyped(KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala:616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset.agg(KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset.count(KeyValueGroupedDataset.scala:733)
```

I have been unable to debug what I am doing wrong. How can I resolve this?